# Multiple inheritence for method without parameters

Tags: java, generics

Can java generics help to force a method without parameters to return an object extending A and implementing B?

This is what I have currently:

```
public abstract class UI {
    public abstract MainPage getMainPage();

    public void refresh() {
        MainPage mainPage = getMainPage();
        if ( ! (mainPage instanceof AbstractLayout)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Please subclass AbstractLayout");
        }
        // do stuff with mainPage
    }
}

public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    public MainPage getMainPage() {
        return new MyPage();  // wrong: does not subclass AbstractLayout
    }
}

public class MyPage implements MainPage {}

public class AbstractLayout {}

public interface MainPage {}
```

I would like the erasure of getMainPage() to somehow force its override to return an instance of AbstractLayout. As it is now, I am checking this at runtime, but I would like to do this compile time. Can it be done?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extend AbstractLayout from MainPage". AbstractLayout is a class, MainPage is an interface. I don't follow. As for generics, adding it to the return type of getMainPage() has no effect on what the compiler accepts, since T does not come from a parameter.

Comment: I've removed my comment as it was probably a bit ambiguous. I'm not really sure if your design is very ... clever or good. Why should `getMainPage()` return an `AbstractLayout` - furthermore as it is not linked to a page in any way (in your design)? Does the `MainPage` serve any real purpose (includes methods?). If you don't restrict the generics to a type you can fill in any class - so `UI<T>` and defining `public T getMainPage()` will therefore return any type you specify with a concrete class.

Comment: `public class MyPage extends AbstractLayout implements MainPage {}`

Comment: "Why should getMainPage return an AbstractLayout?" Because UI puts it in a layout container. "Does the MainPage serve any real purpose?" Of course. For UI to be able to take control of this particular layout, it must be able to interact with it. "... will therefore return any type ...". That's precisely the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use generics to force the return type of getMainPage to extend AbstractLayout and implement MainPage without having AbstractLayout implement MainPage. One solution is to make UI generic.

This will result in a compiler error:

```
public abstract class UI<T extends AbstractLayout & MainPage> {
    public abstract T getMainPage();
}

public class MyUI extends UI<MyPage> { // Compiler error: Bound mismatch

    @Override
    public MyPage getMainPage() {
        return new MyPage();
    }

}

public class MyPage implements MainPage {}

public class AbstractLayout {}

public interface MainPage {}
```

Having MyPage extend AbstractLayout will allow the code to compile:

```
public class MyPage extends AbstractLayout implements MainPage {}
```

Comment: Getting the code to compile is not the problem. The example code already compiles. I am trying to get the compiler to *reject* the override of getMainPage, because MyPage does not subclass AbstractLayout.

Comment: That's precisely what this does. By adding the type parameter, the code will not compile because MyPage does not extend AbstractLayout.

Comment: Brilliant! I guess I wasn't paying attention before. I did what you suggested, and the compiler now rejects the override with "return type MyPage is not compatible with AbstractLayout". Thanks a bunch.